# Is there a way to input 2 strings into 1 string and have them not effect each others input?

Tags: java, regex, string, eclipse

So Lets say I have `ABab` and I want to replace `A` with `ACac`, and `a` with `CAca....`. My output from what I try gives me `ACCAcacBCAcab` when it should be `ACacBCAcab` I'm unsure how to bypass this because as you can see it also changes the lower case a's in the inputted `Acac`. I Want to be able to input these all the way up to `Z` as you can see `haha`, Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Nails 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner i = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[][] comms = { { "ACac", "CAca" }, { "ADad", "DAda" }, { "AEae", "EAea" }, { "AFaf", "FAfa" },
        { "AGag", "GAga" }, { "AHah", "HAha" }, { "AIai", "Iaia" }, { "AJaj", "JAja" }, { "AKak", "KAka" },
        { "ALal", "LAla" }, { "AMam", "MAma" }, { "ANan", "NAna" }, { "AOao", "OAoa" }, { "APap", "PApa" },
        { "AQaq", "QAqa" }, { "ARar", "RAra" }, { "ASas", "SAsa" }, { "ATat", "TAta" }, { "AUau", "UAua" },
        { "AVav", "VAva" }, { "AWaw", "WAwa" }, { "AXax", "XAxa" }, { "AYay", "YAya" }, { "AZaz", "ZAza" } };

        String Master = "ABab";
        String S = Master; //Slave String
        String Tmp = S; 
        System.out.println("Amount of Nails: ");
        int N = i.nextInt(); //Nails
        if(N < 2)
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry, You Must input a number Greater than or Equal to 2");
        }
        if(N == 2)
        {
            System.out.println(Master);
        }
        else
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < N - 2; c++) //C for Counter, subtracting 2 because method wont run if it is <= 2 and 'Comms' starts on 0 which would be 3 Nails
            {
                System.out.println(S);
                S = S.replace("A", Comms[c][0]);
                S = S.replace("a", Comms[c][1]);
                System.out.println(S);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The lower case letter represent the Composite of the Upper case letter which is why there are 2 entries for each 1 added "Nail". I am making this program to be able to create a formula generator for this puzzle:
[Nail Puzzle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-v6pmZzxL0). The Video creator also explains some of the math if that'll help.
Thanks.

Comment: To me this doesn't look like a question relating to any of its tags, its just a matter of finding a suitable algorithm, and for this the title of the question is less than clear.

Comment: @Stephan Hernmann - I dont have the rep to choose any suitable tags anyways, and I was working in eclipse, was doing java, needed string help, and I dont remember why I put regex but i can assume because this entire project is based on a puzzle. You are right I need to find an algorithm AND I have no idea even how to comprehend this to make a prim and proper title because my knowledge in code is very basic, sorry about the title

Answer (score 3):

You can use a placeholder. Replace the character to placeholder and replace the placeholder to the actual string.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Q47028607 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[][] comms = { { "ACac", "CAca" }, { "ADad", "DAda" }, { "AEae", "EAea" }, { "AFaf", "FAfa" },
        { "AGag", "GAga" }, { "AHah", "HAha" }, { "AIai", "Iaia" }, { "AJaj", "JAja" }, { "AKak", "KAka" },
        { "ALal", "LAla" }, { "AMam", "MAma" }, { "ANan", "NAna" }, { "AOao", "OAoa" }, { "APap", "PApa" },
        { "AQaq", "QAqa" }, { "ARar", "RAra" }, { "ASas", "SAsa" }, { "ATat", "TAta" }, { "AUau", "UAua" },
        { "AVav", "VAva" }, { "AWaw", "WAwa" }, { "AXax", "XAxa" }, { "AYay", "YAya" }, { "AZaz", "ZAza" } };
    String master = "ABab";
    System.out.println("Amount of Nails: ");
    int N = scanner.nextInt();
    if (N < 2) {
      System.out.println("Sorry, You Must input a number Greater than or Equal to 2");
    } else if (N == 2) {
      System.out.println(master);
    } else {
      for (int c = 0; c < N - 2; c++) {
        System.out.println(master);
        master = master.replace("A", "$1");
        master = master.replace("a", "$2");
        master = master.replace("$1", comms[c][0]);
        master = master.replace("$2", comms[c][1]);
        System.out.println(master);
      }
    }
    scanner.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something Like that Dean Xu, but I litteraly just thought of changing the character AFTER it changes the others haha so here is my ending code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Nails 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner i = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[][] Comms = {{"AC1c", "CAc1"}, {"AD1d", "DAd1"}, {"AE1e", "EAe1"}, {"AF1f", "FAf1"}, {"AG1g", "GAg1"}, {"AH1h", "HAh1"}, {"AI1i", "I1i1"}, {"AJ1j", "JAj1"}, {"AK1k", "KAk1"}, {"AL1l", "LAl1"}, {"AM1m", "MAm1"}, {"AN1n", "NAn1"}, {"AO1o", "OAo1"}, {"AP1p", "PAp1"}, {"AQ1q", "QAq1"}, {"AR1r", "RAr1"}, {"AS1s", "SAs1"}, {"AT1t", "TAt1"}, {"AU1u", "UAu1"}, {"AV1v", "VAv1"}, {"AW1w", "WAw1"}, {"AX1x", "XAx1"}, {"AY1y", "YAy1"}, {"AZ1z", "ZAz1"}};
        String Master = "ABab";
        String S = Master; //Slave String
        String Tmp = S; 
        System.out.println("Amount of Nails: ");
        int N = i.nextInt(); //Nails
        if(N < 2)
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry, You Must input a number Greater than or Equal to 2");
        }
        if(N == 2)
        {
            System.out.println(Master);
        }
        else
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < N - 2; c++) //C for Counter, subtracting 2 because method wont run if it is <= 2 and 'Comms' starts on 0 which would be 3 Nails
            {
                S = S.replace("A", Comms[c][0]);
                S = S.replace("a", Comms[c][1]);
                S = S.replace("1", "a");
            }
            System.out.println(S);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: However I can remove the TMP string I thought i was gonna need it

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion :: Use StringBuilder instead of String. Since you are doing multiple operations on string it will affect your performance and memory usage. Use of StringBuilder will improve performance.